# Using `transactions` without `select ... for update`?

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have a table of ranges that should never intersect:

> ```
> id | from | to
> --------------
>  1 |  3   | 5
>  2 |  12  | 14
>  3 |  20  | 24
>  4 |  27  | 30
> ```

I have an algorithm that does the following:

1. Find gaps (gaps in example would be *6-11*, *15-19*, *25-26*,*31-null*)
2. Compute random ranges that do not intersect existig ranges from table
3. Insert these ranges  (for example `insert into table (from,to) values (15,17)` and `insert into table (from,to) values (31,40)`)

Now if this algorithm happens at ***the exact same time*** it would be possible that the range `15-17` and `15-19` would be inserted and that the ranges of my table intersect.

I know that one usually uses `transactions` with `select ... for update` in such a situation. However, I am not really selecting any row that I want to update. Instead, I first compute gaps that do not exist in the database. The computation of the gaps is done with this SQL:

```
SELECT gap_starts, gap_ends  FROM
   (SELECT (t1.to + 1) as gap_starts,
    (SELECT Min(t3.from) - 1 FROM table t3 WHERE t3.from > t1.to) as gap_ends
    FROM table t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.from FROM table t2 WHERE t2.from = t1.to +1 )
   )
```

How can I use `transaction` here to make sure that my inserted rows from step 3 are not intersecting?

Comment: Neither transaction nor `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` can help you... your task needs in locking the data which NOT EXISTS! How can you do something with the entity which not exists? You need in `LOCK TABLE` before select/calculate/update and `UNLOCK` after - because you MUSTprevent any data reading for parallel process. In any other case you can only detect that the inserted range which was calculated using old data is overlapped with the recent data.

Comment: He knows that @Akina this question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522444/how-to-lock-table-with-laravel is related to this on.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The author "forget" to tell this... in that case the only way I see is to read documentation for the quering method which allows multi-query. Or, the best way, to call Stored procedure.

Comment: Well @Akina he could try a TEMPORARY table to make a "copy state"  ... `INSERT INTO temp SELECT FROM table2`  it could give a locking read (shared locks) for the complete `table2` table In thoery it could "work"

Comment: @RaymondNijland It's like hammer nails with a microscope... unwise, but possible.

Comment: @Akina I agree with you, locking the complete table seems the best option here. I did not mention the other question here, because the other question is only about how to lock a table in Laravel. I found it out now.

Comment: indeed @Akina i also agree we don't have information how large the table is for "small" tables it's probably fine using that method.. Thats why i also said "work" between qoutes

Answer (score 1):

You need a transaction and it needs to grab the gap with `FOR UPDATE`.  The problem is that you don't have an index to use to help with the task.

I suggest that having both a `start` and `end` in a row makes the task difficult.  If, instead, there were only a `start` (or, equivalently, `end`), you could have an index and use `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` successfully.

Since you have gaps in the table, you would need a way to represent "real range" versus "unused range".  That would involve another column (which you might already have).

Building such a structure, plus code to grab part of a gap, is found [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) , where I discuss (as an example) associating ranges of IP-addresses with their 'owner'.  I use a special owner_id to indicate that a range is 'unassigned'.

The code was designed with speed in mind, since searching on start..end performs miserably at scale.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this design idea. However, I also want to give a user the ability to change the ranges. I think this would get in conflict with that design, because the algorithm may lock all rows with `owner='0'`, but if another user changes a `range` he would insert new rows with `owner=0`. Its not a high scale project. There might be only 20 inserts per day. Maybe its best if simply lock the table while inserting new ranges in my table.

Comment: @Adam - It's more complex, but don't lock all owner=0 rows.  Instead, locate the next and previous `start` values (hence complexity) and lock just that range.